# Как отфильтровать не-числовые символы в строке? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, строки

Есть строка:

```
var phone = '+7 (999) 111-22-33';
```

Как, используя JS, удалить из неё пробелы и все символы, чтобы на выходе получить **79991112233**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var phone = '+7 (999) 111-22-33';
console.log(phone.replace(/\D/g, ""));
```